# Nesting entity groups?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a data model where I'm not sure if I'll get any benefit from nesting classes in entity groups. The basic model is that User owns many horses, a horse can only own one saddle:

```
// Model 1, nest everything:
User
    Horse
        Saddle
    Horse
        Saddle

// Model 2: Just let them all be siblings.
User
    Horse
    Horse
    Saddle
    Saddle
```

I'm not sure if I gain any advantage over nesting saddle instances under a horse, or if I should just leave them all as siblings.

Generating keys:

```
// Model 1:
Key key = new KeyFactory.Builder(
  User.class.getSimpleName(), userid)
    .addChild(Horse.class.getSimpleName(), horseid)
      .addChild(Saddle.class.getSimpleName(), saddleid).getKey();

// Model 2:
Key key = new KeyFactory.Builder(
  User.class.getSimpleName(), userid)
    .addChild(Saddle.class.getSimpleName(), saddleid).getKey();
```

So generating keys is more work for situation 1, and I'm wondering if I should just switch to situation 2 instead, if I'm not gaining any advantage over the additional nesting? The operations I have to do:

1. Delete a horse and its saddle.
2. Create a horse with a saddle.
3. Update a horse and its saddle.
4. Get a horse by itself.
5. Get a horse and its saddle at the same time.

Both models give me all the above, I think. Maybe model #1 offers the advantage that the entire User object doesn't have to be locked when performing operations only on a Saddle?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keysandentitygroups.html):

> Every entity with a given root entity
>   as an ancestor is in the same entity
>   group. All entities in a group are
>   stored in the same datastore node.

And:

> Only use entity groups when they are
>   needed for transactions. For other
>   relationships between entities, use
>   ReferenceProperty properties and Key
>   values, which can be used in queries.

Both of your models will result in one entity group per user, regardless of nesting. If you just want to represent a hierarchy of objects, you should avoid entity groups entirely and use a ReferenceProperty.